# find all occurrences of 'can be interpreted as time'

Tags: php, regex, parsing, time

Is there an efficient way to search a message for substrings which might represent a time?

For example, this message:

> let's meet tomorrow at 14:30 or do you prefer 2:30pm?

should return `('14:30', '2:30pm')`. Finding hh:mm times can be easily achieved using a simple regex, but I'm wondering if there are existing solutions to find more than the simple cases.

Comment: What else would you want to match?

Comment: Let's discuss this at 5 o'clock, shall we?  No; I could do noon, though - but midnight is right out.  I'm busy until a quarter past; I can can give you 30 minutes then, but have a meeting at a quarter to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex I came up with:

```
^((\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s?([ap]m?)?)|(\d{1,2}\s?[ap]m?))$
```

It matches:

```
2:10
14:20
10:00am
3:49p
4pm
10a
```

But not:

```
12
22:342
14:0
20rpm
```

As seen on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/tJXSHj9MNC)

I think it would be just too difficult for it to be much smarter than this. For example, "I have 2 classes after 2 tomorrow" you can't expect a program to correctly identify which numbers can be interpreted as time unless it's able to understand semantics - but that's a whole different story

PS: The regex also matches string like 99:99 am, which can be fixed but would make the regex even more confusing and just not worth to fix IMO.

Comment: a "little bit" more complex than my own regex but definitely a good start.

Comment: Simplified regex: `^\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*(?:[ap]m?)?|\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m?$` I removed all those capturing groups. This will yield in a cleaner result array.

Comment: @niki You broke some of the functionality (now it matches 11:111), but I like it. I actually had something cleaner, but I figured the OP'd would want to match the whole thing anyways so the groups could be ignored.